# Is there a way to style an element which has no matching selector

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I need to style certain elements in my react application, but those elements do not have any id or class, how can I style those elements?

```
<table>
  <table-row>
    <table-cell>
      #shadow-root
      'the text is here' <!-- need to style this, but it has no matching selector or style. -->
    </table-cell>
  </table-row>
</table>
```

Comment: Assuming you mean you want to style the text "#shadow-root" differently than the text "the text is here", the answer is: you can't do that.  You'll need to modify the DOM to wrap each thing you want styled differently in its own node.

Comment: `#shadow-root` means the shadow-root of an inserted web-component. You can try to style this text by adding a class to the `table-cell`

Comment: I want to style only 'the text is here' part. adding a class to table-cell is not working. How can I modify the DOM to wrap each thing I want to style differently in its own node?